Unable to filterBounds in Google Earth Engine for ERA5 Land in python api
I am using GEE in python to attempt to get ERA5-Land data for a region like California. However, when I try to filterBounds(), it doesn't seem to work. Here is an example using Landsat that works.
import ee
ee.initialize()

california = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [-124.5, 32.5],
  [-124.5, 42.5],
  [-114.5, 42.5],
  [-114.5, 32.5],
  [-124.5, 32.5]
])

collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
fc = collection.filterBounds(california).filterDate('2023-01-01,2023-01-31)
bounds = fc.geometry().bounds()
print(bounds.getInfo())

This returns
{'geodesic': False, 'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-126.83346603418426, 30.680497873221675], [-111.99113604798686, 30.680497873221675], [-111.99113604798686, 44.24133036635237], [-126.83346603418426, 44.24133036635237], [-126.83346603418426, 30.680497873221675]]]} 

However, when I replace 'LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2' with ERA5-Land ("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR"), I get the output
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-180, -90], [180, -90], [180, 90], [-180, 90], [-180, -90]]]}

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

If you clip each image individually, it seems to work. Not sure why the Landsat and ERA5-Land datasets are different.
clipped = fc.map(lambda image: image.clip(California))
bounds = clipped.geometry().bounds()
print(bounds.getInfo())


.filter() only removes rows from a table or items from a collection.  The operation you're asking about is clip().

As explained by Noel, filtering will select every image of the collection that interstect with the selected FeatureCollection. Era5 being 1 day/full world image you get the full world.
so yes if you really want each underlying image to be cut to the geometry you need to map the clip method to each image:
clipped = fc.map(lambda i: ee.image(i).clip(caliornia))

Note that for landsat imagery this will lead to partially cut raw images that intersect your polygon and I guess it's not what you want so for landsat to get a single date cut image you need to group them by day (this example uses geetools for this)
import ee, geetools 

ic = (
    ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(california)
    .fitlerDate("2023-01-01", "2023-01-31")
    .geetools.reduceInterval("first", "day", 1) # mosaic 1 image per day
    .map(lambda i: i.clip(california))
)

Note
I think you don't need to perform this clip at all. In GEE every computation is realized pixel wise so the only moment you need to clip the image is when you export the end result of your process to any destination (local, assets, GCP...). This is when GEE will identify which pixels effectively need to be computed and the one that shouldn't. In short it's making your life easier.
